# Can't place Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

See http://jsbin.com/ocufez/1/edit

```
$('div').tooltip
  placement: 'right'
```

This is not placing tooltip at right side of div.

How can I place the tooltip?

NOTE: You have to click `run with JS` and hover last div in JSBin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think jQueryUI - **jquery-ui.min.js** is conflicting with **bootstrap.js** as they both have a **.tooltip()** If you remove jQueryUI you'll see the Bootstrap tooltip on the right.

or you can put jquery-ui.min.js before bootstrap.js...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add in element:

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on right"
```

Found in http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips